# Stopping a request in Firefox, restart and do it again

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a listener that blocks a specific site just before the navigator makes the request.

```
window.addEventListener('load', registerMyListener, false);
function registerMyListener() {
    window.getBrowser().addTabsProgressListener(myListener);
}
var myListener = {
        onStateChange:function(aBrowser,aProgress,aRequest,aFlag,aStatus) {
                if ( /* check if the request is 'www.example.com' */) {
                        blockSite(aBrowser, aRequest.URI.host, aRequest.URI.spec);
                }
        }
}
```

Here's my problem:
I go to "www.google.com" (allowed url) and the page is loaded as usual. Then I type "www.example.com" (blocked url) and the blockSite function is excecuted, stopping the request using "window.stop()" and displaying an alert.
When I restart firefox, it loads "www.google.com" (the last url requested) but with "www.example.com" in the address bar.

What event I need to use to stop the request of 'www.example.com' and Firefox still process that request so when I restart, Firefox request it again (and not "www.google.com")?

I think the problem is when I stop the request, becouse I do it before Firefox "knows where I'm going".

Comment: can you see the headers before the request "continues"

Comment: I never make the request, that is the point.